# A tcolorbox whose text starts on the same line as the title?

Tags: tcolorbox

A tcolorbox looks something like:

```
**Title**

The text begins here, that is on a line below the title line ...
```

What I would like is:

```
 **Title**  The text begins here, that is on the same line as the title ...
```

I just found the answer on page 19 of the manual for version 3.80. (I had mistakingly looked at version 2.80 where I found it only as a theorem.)

Comment: With `biblatex` you can print a bibliography by `category`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `detach title`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[detach title,
                  fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=red,
                  before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
                  title=My title]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found it 2 minutes ago and was so eager to edit my question that I did not see your answer.